# RuntimeError: Expected to mark a variable ready only once error in Databricks notebook

Tags: pytorch, databricks, huggingface-transformers, aws-databricks

I'm using a `Single Node` machine with `g5.2xlarge` to fine tune a LLaMa-2 model. My Come Notebook runs very smoothly on Colab but when I try to run it on `Databricks`, it throws me the exact error given below:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-65240085594578>, line 1
----> 1 fine_tuning_trainer.train()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/utils/autologging_utils/safety.py:451, in safe_patch.<locals>.safe_patch_function(*args, **kwargs)
    436 if (
    437     active_session_failed
    438     or autologging_is_disabled(autologging_integration)
   (...)
    445     # warning behavior during original function execution, since autologging is being
    446     # skipped
    447     with set_non_mlflow_warnings_behavior_for_current_thread(
    448         disable_warnings=False,
    449         reroute_warnings=False,
    450     ):
--> 451         return original(*args, **kwargs)
    453 # Whether or not the original / underlying function has been called during the
    454 # execution of patched code
    455 original_has_been_called = False

File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/huggingface_patches/transformers.py:54, in _create_patch_function.<locals>.patched_fit_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
     52 call_succeeded = False
     53 try:
---> 54     model = original_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     55     call_succeeded = True
     56     return model

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1539, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1534     self.model_wrapped = self.model
   1536 inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(
   1537     self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1538 )
-> 1539 return inner_training_loop(
   1540     args=args,
   1541     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1542     trial=trial,
   1543     ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1544 )

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1809, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1806     self.control = self.callback_handler.on_step_begin(args, self.state, self.control)
   1808 with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):
-> 1809     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1811 if (
   1812     args.logging_nan_inf_filter
   1813     and not is_torch_tpu_available()
   1814     and (torch.isnan(tr_loss_step) or torch.isinf(tr_loss_step))
   1815 ):
   1816     # if loss is nan or inf simply add the average of previous logged losses
   1817     tr_loss += tr_loss / (1 + self.state.global_step - self._globalstep_last_logged)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2665, in Trainer.training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2663         scaled_loss.backward()
   2664 else:
-> 2665     self.accelerator.backward(loss)
   2667 return loss.detach() / self.args.gradient_accumulation_steps

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py:1853, in Accelerator.backward(self, loss, **kwargs)
   1851     self.scaler.scale(loss).backward(**kwargs)
   1852 else:
-> 1853     loss.backward(**kwargs)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:487, in Tensor.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    477 if has_torch_function_unary(self):
    478     return handle_torch_function(
    479         Tensor.backward,
    480         (self,),
   (...)
    485         inputs=inputs,
    486     )
--> 487 torch.autograd.backward(
    488     self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
    489 )

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:200, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    195     retain_graph = create_graph
    197 # The reason we repeat same the comment below is that
    198 # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
    199 # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
--> 200 Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    201     tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    202     allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/function.py:274, in BackwardCFunction.apply(self, *args)
    270     raise RuntimeError("Implementing both 'backward' and 'vjp' for a custom "
    271                        "Function is not allowed. You should only implement one "
    272                        "of them.")
    273 user_fn = vjp_fn if vjp_fn is not Function.vjp else backward_fn
--> 274 return user_fn(self, *args)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/checkpoint.py:157, in CheckpointFunction.backward(ctx, *args)
    153 if len(outputs_with_grad) == 0:
    154     raise RuntimeError(
    155         "none of output has requires_grad=True,"
    156         " this checkpoint() is not necessary")
--> 157 torch.autograd.backward(outputs_with_grad, args_with_grad)
    158 grads = tuple(inp.grad if isinstance(inp, torch.Tensor) else None
    159               for inp in detached_inputs)
    161 return (None, None) + grads

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:200, in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    195     retain_graph = create_graph
    197 # The reason we repeat same the comment below is that
    198 # some Python versions print out the first line of a multi-line function
    199 # calls in the traceback and some print out the last line
--> 200 Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    201     tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    202     allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)

RuntimeError: Expected to mark a variable ready only once. This error is caused by one of the following reasons: 1) Use of a module parameter outside the `forward` function. Please make sure model parameters are not shared across multiple concurrent forward-backward passes. or try to use _set_static_graph() as a workaround if this module graph does not change during training loop.2) Reused parameters in multiple reentrant backward passes. For example, if you use multiple `checkpoint` functions to wrap the same part of your model, it would result in the same set of parameters been used by different reentrant backward passes multiple times, and hence marking a variable ready multiple times. DDP does not support such use cases in default. You can try to use _set_static_graph() as a workaround if your module graph does not change over iterations.
Parameter at index 191 has been marked as ready twice. This means that multiple autograd engine  hooks have fired for this particular parameter during this iteration. You can set the environment variable TORCH_DISTRIBUTED_DEBUG to either INFO or DETAIL to print parameter names for further debugging.
```

Here is my code for Fine Tuning LLaMa v-2:

```py
# Model and tokenizer names
base_model_name = "NousResearch/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
refined_model = "finetuned_llama-7b"

# Tokenizer
llama_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model_name, trust_remote_code=True)
llama_tokenizer.pad_token = llama_tokenizer.eos_token # llama_tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
llama_tokenizer.padding_side = "right"  # Fix for fp16

# Quantization Config
quant_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16, #torch.bfloat16
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant = False 

base_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    base_model_name,
    quantization_config=quant_config,
    device_map= {"": 0})


base_model.config.use_cache = False # Gradient checkpointing is used by default but not compatible with caching
base_model.config.pretraining_tp = 1


# LoRA Config
peft_parameters = LoraConfig(
    r = 8, 
    lora_alpha=16, 
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    target_modules = ['q_proj','v_proj','k_proj'],
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM"
)

# Training Params
train_params = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="/tmp",
    num_train_epochs=2,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
    optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_steps=25,
    logging_steps=25,
    learning_rate=3e-4,
    weight_decay=0.001,
    fp16=False, 
    bf16=False,
    max_grad_norm=0.3,
    max_steps=-1,
    warmup_ratio=0.03,
    group_by_length=True,
    lr_scheduler_type="cosine", 
    report_to= "none",
    log_level = "debug", 
    push_to_hub = False, 
)

# Trainer
fine_tuning_trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=base_model,
    train_dataset=train_data,
    eval_dataset = val_data,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=None,
    peft_config=peft_parameters,
    tokenizer=llama_tokenizer,
    args=train_params
)


fine_tuning_trainer.train()
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: I switched to Sagemaker. But you can turn the DDP trace param off. I forgot the param name and link but you'll find a github issue mentioning the same @LidorEliyahuShelef

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef found it" `ddp_find_unused_parameters=False` and Turn off Gradient Checkpointing in case otherwise.

Comment: In which object does this key belong though?

Comment: `TrainingArguments`. Also, there might be some param that might be causing this issue. Ask your frien ds to look at you code. In one instance, I was adding tokens to the tokenizer but it was full. In other instance, my labels for classification was float instead of int. so there could be other reasons too

Comment: After everything here I still get the following problem [Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78211526/pytorch-attributeerror-torch-dtype-object-has-no-attribute-itemsize) can you help me?

Comment: databricks is crazy my friend. I stopped using it for exactly same reasons