# PyTorch: AttributeError: 'torch.dtype' object has no attribute 'itemsize'

Tags: python, pytorch, databricks, huggingface, peft

I am trying to follow this article on medium [Article](https://dassum.medium.com/fine-tune-large-language-model-llm-on-a-custom-dataset-with-qlora-fb60abdeba07).

I had a few problems with it so the remain chang eI did was to the `TrainingArguments` object I added `gradient_checkpointing_kwargs={'use_reentrant':False},`.

So now I have the following objects:

```py
peft_training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir = output_dir,
    warmup_steps=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    max_steps=100, #1000
    learning_rate=2e-4,
    optim="paged_adamw_8bit",
    logging_steps=25,
    logging_dir="./logs",
    save_strategy="steps",
    save_steps=25,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=25,
    do_eval=True,
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
    gradient_checkpointing_kwargs={'use_reentrant':False},
    report_to="none",
    overwrite_output_dir = 'True',
    group_by_length=True,
)

peft_model.config.use_cache = False

peft_trainer = transformers.Trainer(
    model=peft_model,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    args=peft_training_args,
    data_collator=transformers.DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False),
)
```

And when I call `peft_trainer.train()` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'torch.dtype' object has no attribute 'itemsize'
```

I'm using Databricks, and my pytorch version is `2.0.1+cu118`

Answer (score 1):

The `itemsize` attribute doesn't seem to have documentation in PyTorch 2.0.x, which suggests that it doesn't exist in that version. (Try searching "itemsize" in the docs for [versions 2.0](https://pytorch.org/docs/2.0/search.html?q=itemsize) and [version 2.2](https://pytorch.org/docs/2.2/search.html?q=itemsize) yourself.) The probable reason for this is that one of the packages you're using assumes a Pytorch version greater than the one you're using.

Moreover, if you look at the Medium article author's own notebook for this tutorial [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/dassum/finetune-phi-2-on-custom-dataset?source=post_page-----fb60abdeba07--------------------------------), you will see that pip install errors out, suggesting their code isn't runnable.

The best solution I can propose (given that the medium author didn't seem to provide a list of requirement versions) is to create a conda environment which will try to resolve the various package dependencies for you, or to reach out to the author for a precise requirements file so that you can replicate their work. If they cannot do this for you, then don't trust their results.

Answer (score 0):

if you use transformers version latest(v4.39.1), plz try to downgrade to v4.38.2.
I solved it that way.

Comment: If I do it I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.cache_utils'` when I use the following code: `original_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, 
                                                      device_map=device_map,
                                                      quantization_config=bnb_config,
                                                      trust_remote_code=True,
                                                      use_auth_token=True
                                                      )`

Comment: `pip uninstall -y transformers
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
`

https://huggingface.co/DiscoResearch/mixtral-7b-8expert/discussions/9  

maybe same problem.

Comment: That will install the latest version which results in the original problem And the opposite of your answer lol

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to torch-2.1.2 will resolve that error.

Comment: Done that, now it causes me to get the following error: `TypeError: Accelerator.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gradient_accumulation_kwargs'`